# Collecting outputs from train_minibatch()

Tags: cntk

The relevant part of my snippet is as below :

```
 feature_output = network['output'].find_by_name('fc8').outputs
 _, output = trainer.train_minibatch(data, (feature_output))
print(output.keys())
print(output[dict_keys(feature_output]))
```

It gives me an error as follows :

```
dict_keys([Output('fc8', [#], [1000])])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainoverfeataccurate.py", line 325, in <module>
    warm_up=0, max_epochs=epochs)
  File "trainoverfeataccurate.py", line 250, in overfeataccuratetraining
    restore, profiling, print_freq=1)
  File "trainoverfeataccurate.py", line 145, in train_and_test
    print(output[feature_output])
KeyError: (Output('fc8', [#], [1000]),)
```

I also tried  `_, output = trainer.train_minibatch(data,{'a' : feature_output})` 
But it gives me the following error 
`TypeError: cannot convert key of dictionary to N4CNTK8VariableE`

What is the right approach to collect outputs when using `train_minibatch` ?

Answer (score 0):

The output of the network is a tuple, so you need to get the first element. Then the name you are looking for is the uid. E.g.

```
feature_output[0].uid
```